# I got an error while creating react app. How do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Answer (score 0):

`npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app`

This could be a local caching issue. Try the command `npm cache clean --force` using administrator mode in your terminal and then try again with the same command - `npx create-react-app my-app`.